# Как в django datalist убрать pk?

Tags: python, django, datalist

Вывожу `datalist`, но выводится `pk`. Прочитал, что его можно убрать в `data-value` вот таким образом https://stackoverflow.com/a/48076273/9653855. Как мне переписать код, чтобы у меня выводился `datalist` в таком формате `<option data-value="1" value="DjangoOneLove"></option>`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**мой forms**

```
class ListTextWidget(forms.Select):
    template_name = 'include/_forms_orders_datalist.html'

    def format_value(self, value):
        if value == '' or value is None:
            return ''
        if self.is_localized:
            return formats.localize_input(value)
        return str(value)

class ChoiceTxtField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    widget=ListTextWidget()

class SimpleOrderAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
        #service = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Service.objects.all(), widget=ListTextWidget())
        service = ChoiceTxtField(queryset=Service.objects.order_by('-used'))   
    
        class Meta:
            model = Orders
            fields = ['service']
```

**мой forms_orders_datalist.html**

```
<input id="ajax_input_{{ widget.name }}" list="{{ widget.name }}" autocomplete="off"
    {% if widget.value != None %} name="{{ widget.name }}" value="{{ widget.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %}
    {% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
    <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-warning text-dark" id="ajax-{{ widget.name }}" name="ajax-{{ widget.name }}"></span>

<datalist id="{{ widget.name }}">
    {% for group_name, group_choices, group_index in widget.optgroups %}
        {% if group_name %}
<optgroup label="{{ group_name }}">{% endif %}{% for option in group_choices %}
  {% include option.template_name with widget=option %}{% endfor %}{% if group_name %}
</optgroup>{% endif %}{% endfor %}
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй это выводится не `Pk`, а номер группы, так `optgroup` и выводит информацию:

[image: 1]

Вам нужно, например, заменить его на Select